# $P(z) = z^3 − 6z^2 + (21 + 4i)z − 80 − ki$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers

> Let $P(z) = z^3 − 6z^2 + (21 + 4i)z − 80 − ki$. If $P(1 − 4i) = 0$, find the remaining two roots and the value of $k$.

What crossed my mind first was using Vieta's formulas and the given root. However, setting up the sum, product, and sum of products of two roots taken at a time produced:

$5+4i=(a+c)+(b+d)i$

$21+4i=(a+c+ac+4b+4d-bd)+(b+d+ad+bc-4a-4c)i$

$80+ki=(ac-bd+4ad+4bc)+(ad+bc-4ac+4bd)i$

Some of these expressions are rather unwieldy and I am not sure how to manipulate them. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: by [polynomial Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division):

$$
z^3 - 6 z^2 + (21 + 4 i) z - 80 = \big(z^2 - (5 + 4 i) z + 20 i\big) \cdot \big(z - (1 - 4 i)\big) + 20 i
$$

Comment: Isn’t there a $-ki$?

Comment: @silverpegasus258 That was left for you to add a $-ki$ on both sides and finish it off.